# How to enable SSL for MySQL workbench for OSX 10.9

Tags: mysql, osx-mavericks, mysql-workbench

I just downloaded MySQL Workbench on Mac OSX 10.9.5, and I am trying to setup a a new connection. I am getting the message:

```
Connection parameters are correct

SSL not enabled
```

I tried looking at the support forum, but as a new user who is not good with server jargon, had trouble understanding what I should be doing.

Comment: I don't know. That is the message I get. I just downloaded MySQL, I've never used it before.

Comment: its just a message  you an connect to ur db though'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there was no relevant problem, turned out to be just a message I got when I tested connection.

Comment: +1. The message returned back is confusing and non-intuitive, and looks like an error. Thanks for confirming that the message should be expected.

Comment: Ha! I came here too because I thought it was an error message. Thanks for posting your answer.